# What's wrong with this XPath expression

Tags: xpath, xforms, xpath-2.0

I want to display students in a repeat table called 'table1'. when the user click on one of them the details of the student enrollments will be displayed.

I ttried this, taking the index from the table then I compared the student id in the enrollment instance with the id in the students instance.

```
   <xf:repeat nodeset="/instance('enrollInstance')/enrollment[Student_idStudent=student[index('table1')]/idStudent]">
```

nothing is displayed when I write this

```
  <xf:output ref="Course_idCourse"/>
```

where `Course_idCourse` is an element in the enrollment

the xml file looks like this

```
  </enrollment>
       <Course_idCourse>1</Course_idCourse>
       <Student_idStudent>2</Student_idStudent>
       <year>2014</year>
       <Semester>1</Semester>
       <mark>50</mark>
       <idEnrollment>1</idEnrollment>
  </enrollment>
```

there is a student xml file that looks like this

```
<Student>
 <idStudent />
</Student>
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Show the XML source you're targeting

Comment: Also are you using 1.0 or 2.0? Either way there isn't an index() operation

Comment: index() is a function specific to XForms

Comment: @JWiley I am using XForms

Comment: @JWiley I am using XForms

Answer (score 0):

The issue (based on that example XML) is that you are targeting a non-existant node. Looking at just this bit:

```
/enrollment[Student_idStudent=student[index('table1')]/idStudent]
```

You are looking for an `enrollment` node, that has a `Student_idStudent` child element, with a subsequent child `idStudent` element.

Yet in the example XML you have an `enrollment` element, with a `Student_idStudent` child element that contains text, but no child elements within it. So the Xpath will never match anything.

Comment: thanks, but the student does exist in another xml file (or instance I should say). when I wrote the following I get a good result               `/enrollment[Student_idStudent=1]`

Comment: @user1412823 Yes, that query would becuase there is an `/enrollment/Student_idStudent` node, and you aren't querying for any child nodes of that. If there is another XML file I'd suggest editing that into the question so we have full knowledge of the issue.